# C# multi level node tree

Tags: c#, nodes

Hello I try to achieve this idea shown in picture:
[node tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T5tF.png)

```
public interface IChildNode
{
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

    public IParentNode Parent { get; set; }
}


public interface IParentNode
{
    public bool? IsEnabled { get; set; }

    public List<IChildNode> Childrens { get; set; }
}

public interface IIntermediateNode
{
    public bool? IsEnabled { get; set; }

    public IParentNode Parent { get; set; }

    public List<IChildNode> Childrens { get; set; }
}
```

It would be perfect code if node tree contains ONLY parent and child, problem is it has to be universal.

**Logic needed to achieve:**

- Parent can access child nodes and set IsEnabled value
- Child node can access parent node and set parent IsEnabled value
- Intermediate node can set both child and parent IsEnabled values
- Also intermediate node child or parent can be intermediate node
- Parent, child and intermediate models NEVER be same.

I dont need calculation logic of IsEnabled values.

**Help me achieve needed goal: I only need architecture for this logic(how to set up classes or interfaces to support needed logic)**

code examples below:

Case 1

```
public class Parent : IParentNode
{

}

public class Intermediate : IIntermediateNode
{

}

public class Intermediate2 : IIntermediateNode
{

}

public class Child : IChildNode
{

}
```

Case 2

```
public class Parent : IParentNode
{

}


public class Child : IChildNode
{

}
```

Case 3

```
public class Parent : IParentNode
{

}

public class Intermediate : IIntermediateNode
{

}

public class Child : IChildNode
{

}
```

Comment: What is the Question?

Comment: Updated post. please look again

Comment: Among other things, you seem to be confusing the parent-child concept with the root-branch-leaf concept.  They are different concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically not use types to describe the levels the nodes are in the tree, since that would greatly limit the types of problems you can model. You only really need one interface:

```
public interface INode
{    
    public bool? IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public INode Parent { get; set; }
    public List<INode> Childrens { get; set; }
}
```

When traversing the tree you can keep track of the depth of the current node to determine if you are at the root, leaf, or intermediate nodes.

This model means the root will have a null parent, but that is kind of unavoidable if you want arbitrary depth of the tree. But I would probably argue for removing the parent reference, and instead also keep track of the parents when traversing the tree.